# CountIf returning 0 value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find number of cells in a column who has the value "orange" under "Old Value" header.
But I am getting the value as 0 although I have values in the cells. Please help with the following code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim x As Workbook

    Dim Wks As Worksheet

    Dim aCell As Range

    Dim col As Long

    Dim Var1

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim a

    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\*********\file.xls")

    Set Wks = x.Worksheets("file")

        Set aCell = Wks.Range("A1:X1000").Find(What:="Old Value", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            col = aCell.Column

       For i = 1 To 1000
            Var1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Wks.Cells(i, col), "*orange*")

            Next i
           MsgBox Var1


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`For` loop is not needed here. Instead of

```
For i = 1 To 1000
    Var1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Wks.Cells(i, col), "*orange*")
Next i
```

try

```
Var1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Wks.Columns(col), "*orange*")
```

Answer (score 1):

In general this is a good example of a question, that can be made really minimal. The problem is in the loop, not in the rest of the code.

You do not increment the value of `var1`. Thus, it is rewritten every time. This is how to increment the value:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim Var1 as Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 1000
        Var1 = Var1 + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4), "*orange*")
    Next i

    Debug.Print Var1

End Sub
```

The result is printed in the immediate window.